# How to use dispersion correction with M06-2x in Gaussian 09 or 16?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I would like to perform an optimization calculation using the functional M06-2x using the BJ dispersion correction in Gaussian 0.9. However, I can't find the parameters for this functional as I found for example for B3LyP. Has anyone worked with this?

Comment: I thought M06-2X is already parameterized to reproduce the dispersion energy without adding empirical dispersion?

Comment: I also thought so but I didn't know if it was specifically for Becke Jonhson's correction

Comment: No you misunderstand, sorry if I didn't write it clearly. Becke-Johnson correction is a part of empirical dispersion correction scheme devised by Stefan Grimme and others (read https://manual.q-chem.com/5.2/Ch5.S7.SS2.html). It is added separately to the DFT calculation, i.e. it is evaluated after the SCF step. Whereas M06-2X returns the dispersion energy due to its extensive parameterization i.e. the parameters in the exchange-correlation functions of M06-2X are fitted so that they will give right answers, at least in principle.

Answer (score 1):

It it possible to apply a zero-damped D3 dispersion correction to M06-2X results in Gaussian with the keyword emp=gd3. The parameters are: s6 = 1.0, sr,6 = 1.619, s8 = 0.00.

There are no empirical parameters available for a Becke-Johnson damped D3 correction with M06-2X, either in Gaussian or elsewhere (AFAIK). The Grimme group keeps a list here: https://www.chemie.uni-bonn.de/pctc/mulliken-center/software/dft-d3/functionalsbj

The M06-2X functional includes medium-range correlation contributions by a flexible functional form and extensive parameterization. So it's not "dispersion-corrected" (i.e. correct asymptotic behavior) in the same way as the a posteriori corrections such as D3.